# subalgebras and finitely generated modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $A$ be a $k$-algebra, $B$ be a subalgebra of $A$, and $K$ be a left ideal of $B$ which is finitely generated as a $B$- module. Is $AK$ necessarily a finitely generated $A$-module?

Comment: I wrote $K=Bk_1+Bk_2+\cdots+Bk_n$, and so I could write each element in $AK$ as $ab_1k_1+\cdots+ab_nk_n$. I am not to sure if I am done here though, or I may have missed out something.

Answer (score 1):

Every element from $AK$is of the form $\sum_ia_ix_i$ where  $a_i\in A, x_i\in K$. Then write $x_i$ as in your comment: $x_i=\sum_j b_{ij}k_j$ and you will get the desired.

Comment: @ Babak S.: Sorry, I am not sure I could use chat. Would you like to use e-mail?

Comment: I sent my question. :-)